# How to extract certain value from curl JSON output

Tags: awk, sed, curl, json

I can't use, for some reasons, the `jq` command to parse `curl` JSON output.

I need to extract certain fields using standard Unix tools like `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, etc.

Example of `curl` output:

```json
[
  {
    "case_id": 1500,
    "date": "13:58 02-02-2021",
    "user": "admin",
    "ip": "1.2.3.4",
    "type": "test",
    "active": "true"
  },
  {
    "case_id": 1501,
    "date": "14:45 02-02-2021",
    "user": "admin",
    "ip": "1.2.3.5",
    "type": "dev",
    "active": "false"
  }
]
```

I require a regex to extract the value of the fields `ip` and `type`.

---

I need to extract pure ip 1.2.3.4

I need values in the same line, separated by a comma. For example:

```
1.2.3.4, test  
1.2.3.5, dev
```

Comment: You have a typo in your `curl` output. See `...active":"true"}`. You are missing a quote `"` there.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the _exact_ output you need. Do you want `"1.2.3.4"`? Or maybe `1.2.3.4`? Do you need the values in separate lines? Same line? Space separated? Should this be done on the output of `curl` or will you first save to a file?

Comment: Anyways, is this what you want?  `jq '.[]|.ip,.type'`

Comment: I need to extract pure ip 1.2.3.4 
I need values in same line separated by comma example:

1.2.3.4, test
1.2.3.4, dev

Answer (score 1):

When you have access to `jq` (available as a static binary from https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), this task will be solved by

```bash
curl ... | jq -r '.[] | [ .ip, .type ] | @tsv'
```

This would extract the values of the `ip` and `type` keys for each element in the list returned from `curl`.  These would then be formatted as a tab-delimited list.  Note that the specific formatting of the input JSON document is not important since none of the whitespace (newlines, indentation etc.) between keys and values matter.

Given the example data in the question, this would return

```
1.2.3.4 test
1.2.3.5 dev
```

Would you want your output delimited by a comma and a space instead, then replace `@tsv` with `join(", ")`, or with `@csv` if you require fully CSV-formatted data with quoted fields.

You didn't ask for this, but it would be easy to extract all the entries that have `active` set to the string `true`:

```bash
curl ... | jq -r '.[] | select(.active == "true") | [.ip, .type] | @tsv'
```

Had `active` been a boolean field instead of a string field, this would be even shorter:

```bash
curl ... | jq -r '.[] | select(.active) | [.ip, .type] | @tsv'
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` solution.

```
$ awk -F\" '$2~/^(ip|type)$/{a=a$4","}END{print substr(a,0,length(a)-1)}' file.txt
1.2.3.4,test,1.2.3.5,dev
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variation among others

```
jq -r '.[]| "\(.ip), \(.type)"' < jsonfile
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format is always as presented in your sample, `ip` line followed by `type` line, then this `sed` should work.

```
$ curl ... | sed -n '/ip\|type/{s/[^:]*: "\([^"]*\)"/\1/;N;s/\n[^:]*: "\([^"]*\).*/ \1/p};'
1.2.3.4, test
1.2.3.5, dev
```

If there is the possibility they may be on different lines but `ip` still occurs before `type`, then this alternative should also work.

```
$ curl ... | sed -n '/ip/{s/[^:]*: "\([^"]*\)"/\1/;h;d};/type/{s/[^:]*: "\([^"]*\).*/\1/;x;G;s/\n/ /p}'
1.2.3.4, test
1.2.3.5, dev
```

Answer (score -1):

```
paste -d ',' <(grep -wE 'ip' INPUT | awk -F'"' '{ print $4 }') <(grep -wE 'type' INPUT | awk -F'"' '{ print $4 }')
```

Comment: Note that the JSON in the original question was formatted quite differently: https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/706384/1